# How to trap an error on allKeys when looping down into unknown JSON data?

Tags: ios, json, parsing, nsdictionary

I'm collecting JSON data of unknown structure and trying to sort out the dictionaries and arrays with help from `allKeys`.  But when I reach the bottom, and `allKeys` is applied to something that is not a dictionary, of course, it throws an error and the code crashes.  How can I detect the error and avoid the crash?

Comment: You can start by sharing your code.  But I imagine it involves suggestions like "determine what kind of class it is before you send it a message"

Comment: I don't mind sharing code, but it's kind of a generic question, and yes, borrrden, you're right - that's exactly what I'm looking for.  Below, cynnicaljoy found it for me: `isKindOfClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the object you are working with is indeed a NSDictionary:

```
for (id obj in array)
{
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        for( NSString *aKey in [(NSDictionary *)obj allKeys] )
        {
            NSLog(@"Key: %@", aKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, cynicaljoy!  That's just what I was looking for.